# Before finishing the map in Promise.all it executes next line in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promise

Good Evening All,

Am just trying to create one collection with multiple data, that datas are nested with other collections am trying to call a function to get one id , that id used to call another connection and get some data and id's, that id is used to call other connection like wise i call all connection and gather the data

Here My code

```
firestore.collection("pods/").where("start_date", "==", dformat)
.where("pod_status", "==", "active").get()
 .then((snap: any) => {
        snap.docs.map((docsnap: any) => {
          let details = docsnap.data();
          let pod_docId = docsnap.id;
          let pod_id = details.pod_id;
          let course_id = details.course_id;
          getDocDetails(course_id, firestore, "courses").then(
            (courseData: any) => {
              let course_data = courseData.data(); let levels = course_data.levels;
              Promise.all(
                levels.map((lev: any) => {
                  let level_id = lev;
                   getDocDetails(level_id, firestore, "levels")
                    .then((level_data) => {
                      let result: any = level_data; let level_details = result.data();
                      let modules = level_details.modules;
                      modules.map((module_id: any) => {
                        getDocDetails(module_id, firestore, "modules")
                          .then((module_data) => {
                            let response: any = module_data; let mod_det = response.data(); let sess = mod_det.sessions;
                            sess.map((sess_id: any) => {
                             sessions_id_list.push(sess_id);
                              logger.info("sessions_id_list", sessions_id_list);
                            });
                          })
                          .catch((err) => {
                            logger.info(
                              "Error while getting the Module details",
                              err
                            );
                          });
                      });

                      logger.info("sessions_id_list 2", sessions_id_list);
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      logger.info("Error while getting the Level details", err);
                    });
                })
              );
              logger.info("sessions_id_list 3", sessions_id_list);
              let obj = {
                  pod_docId: pod_docId,
                  pod_id: pod_id,
                  sessions_id_list: sessions_id_list,
                  status: "created",
                  count: 0,
                  completed: 0,
                };
                addQueue(obj, firestore);
              
            }
          );

        });
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        reject(err);
      });
```

Here before pushing the session list , it execute print session list 3 and call addQueue function. How can i overcome this, Help me guys, Thanks in Avance

Comment: Why are you using `Promise.all`? Neither do you pass an array of promises (the `map` callback doesn't return promises - but it should) nor do you do anything (like waiting) with the promise it returns - but you should!

Comment: I don't know about Promise.all , am just using that because some stackoverflow blogs are suggested like that. so am trying , Please give some suggestion to overcome

Comment: You might want to check what they suggested *how* to use it, as well as read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)